# Retrieving dependencies from maven repository

Tags: maven

So for my maven project I require jar dependencies that are available in public repositories and also jar dependencies that are on our company internal repository.

How do I configure my pom.xml so that I will retrieve the dependencies from public repositories and our company internal repository without synchronizing and uploading the stuff from public repos to the company internal repository.

Answer (score 3):

In your settings.xml, which is usually in HOME_DIR/.m2 you need to add the company repository, maven central is included by default.

In the example below it will look for your artifact in each repo in order, starting with maven central.

```
   <profile>
        <id>extras</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>release</id>
                <name>libs-release</name>
                <url>http://internal.corp:8091/artifactory/libs-release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshot</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://internal.corp:8091/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            </repository>       
            <repository>
                <id>codelds</id>
                <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestone</id>
                <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
                <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
```

I would also say that I set up our corporate repository so that is has a virtual repository to maven central.  This means as people use artifacts they will be stored in the company repository.  This is normal practice.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent the libraries I use from say maven central from being stored in the corporate repository? Reason being because I use a more updated version of Spring as opposed to the one stored in the corporate repository that is referenced by other applications in the grand architecture of our project

Comment: Remember every maven artefact is identified by a Group-Artifact-Version (GAV), they should be unique and immutable.  So for instance once spring have uploaded an artefact to maven central, it will never ever change, many people will have copies of this artefact in their corporate repository or their local repository (~/.m2/repository) but that's OK because it's immutable.  In short your corporate repository will contain many different versions of the same artefact.  Especially with a commonly used framework like spring.